# Howto handle connection timeout errors for URLConnection (Java, Android)

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have the following code:

```
        try {
            url = new URL(sURL);
            URLConnection connection  = url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

<Read from reader ...>
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

How can I detect connection-timeout issue? I would like to handle this event as a special case.
IOException is to general for my purpose.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException sox)
    {
        sox.printStackTrace();
    }
```